# How to loop over each file in multiple directories in R

Tags: r

I have an object called `wanted.bam` with the list of wanted file names  for all the .bam (is the extension) files in three of my directories `path1,path2,path3`. I am looping over all these directories to search for the wanted files. What I am trying to do is look for wanted files by looping over each directory and implement a `FUNCTION` in each file. This loop works for all the matched file in the first directory, but as it progresses to another directory, it breaks giving an error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  failed to open BamFile: file(s) do not exist:
  'sort.bam'
```

my code:

```
bam.dir<- c("path1","path2","path3")
    for (j in 1:length(bam.dir)){
    all.bam.files <- list.files(bam.dir[j])
    all.bam.files <- grep(wanted.names, all.bam.files, value=TRUE)           
    print(paste("The wanted number of bam files in this directory:", (length(all.bam.files))))     
      if(length(all.bam.files)==0){
        next
      }else{
    setwd(bam.dir[j])
    }
    print(paste("The working directory number:",j,":",(getwd())))

    ## ****using another loop here for each file to implement a function*****
    all.FAD<- {}
    for(i in 1:length(all.bam.files)){
    output<- FUNCTION(all.bam.files[i])
    }
  }
```

Comment: As @nongkrong was trying to say look at the output of `sapply(bam.dir, list.files, pattern="+[.bam]$")`. You should be able to work a function on that without any for loops.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to be changing working directory like this.  Instead, use the option in `list.files`, `full.names=TRUE`, to return the full path of your files.  Then, you can just use `read.csv`, or whatever, on the full path name without need to change directory.  Your code is failing because after you set directory, the relative path to the next directory is changed.

If you want to keep changing directories, just make sure you set the directory back to the base directory at the end of the loop.

Comment: The full name option doesn't work for me as I have to get the file name in all.bam.files in the output. When you say make sure you set the directory back to the base directory at the end of the loop, do you mean I need to set the setwd as the director where my code is present? Do I need to set this outside the loop?

Comment: @MAPK If you need the filename, you can just extact it from the long string, or if you dont want to use regex, just run `list.files` twice, once to get the short names, once for the full path.  Setting directory isn't good because you will always have these problems about relative paths.  But, if that is how you are doing it, you just need to keep track of the directory you start in, and make sure at the end of the loop you can start over from there.